# Understanding execution hierarchy in activiti

Tags: activiti

My process definition structure is like this:

```
<process>
   <startEvent....>
   <subProcess id="aaa"....>
     <multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics....>
     <userTask id="bbb"....>
.......
</process>
```

In unit test, I launch the process for a single set of input parameters(meaning only one subprocess), and it is waiting at user task. I query for number of executions in the system. I get 4 executions.

I am not able to figure out why it is 4. Process instance accounts for one, and sub process for another. What are 2 other executions?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience each process instance execution or sub process instance execution creates a child execution in which it executes all the activities in itself; therefore you get 4 executions instead of 2. As to why activiti behaves in this way; I would like to know that myself...